# macOS tkinter: how does filetypes of askopenfilename work

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter, file-type

#### My Questions

1. Can't switch among `filetypes` in the `Filter` (see picture below) since they are in grey mode, if set `filetypes` as seen with my code below:

```py
filetypes = [ 
            ("Python File", "*.py"), 
            ("Image File", "*.bmp"),
            ("All Files", "*.*")
            ]
```

2. Though the default filetype is `.py` we can also choose `.bmp` in the window since the `test.bmp` is highlighted. This means the `filetypes`, `.py` and `.bmp`, can be activated at the same time. Is this `Filter` behavior normal?

What I expect is that I can single out one type from the set of `filetypes` and these options should be mutually exclusive, (i.e., if select `Python File (.py)` in the `Filter`, then ONLY `.py` files will be available to be chosen in the window).
See image:
[image: Screenshot of dialog]

#### Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
# from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
# from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilenames

filetypes = [ 
            ("Python File", "*.py"), 
            ("Image File", "*.bmp"),
            ("All Files", "*.*")
            ]

def OpenFile():
    p = askopenfilename(initialdir="../",
                           filetypes =filetypes,
                           title = "Choose a file.")
    print ("Path to File: \n", p)
    #Using try in case user types in unknown file 
    # or closes without choosing a file.
    # try:
    #     with open(p, 'r') as f:
    #         print("Content of File:\n", f.read())
    # except:
    #     print("Error!")

root = Tk()
root.title( "File Opener")
label = ttk.Label(root, 
                    text ="File Read Test!", 
                    foreground="red", 
                    font=("Helvetica", 16))
label.pack()

menu = Menu(root)
root.geometry("300x200")
root.config(menu=menu)

file = Menu(menu)
file.add_command(label = 'Open', command = OpenFile)
file.add_command(label = 'Exit', command = root.quit)
menu.add_cascade(label = 'File', menu = file)

root.mainloop()
```

#### More examples:

- What if delete `("All Files", "*.*")` as in the below code? **Still** cannot switch between file types and both `.py` and `.bmp` are active. And all other file types are out of scope the same as previous settings.

```py
filetypes = [ 
            ("Python File", "*.py"), 
            ("Image File", "*.bmp")]
```

[image: Screenshot of dialog]

- If I leave only `("All Files", "*.*")`, the result is what I expect and `*.*` finally comes to effects the dialog.

```py
filetypes = [("All Files", "*.*")]
```

[image: Screenshot of dialog]

#### System version info:

- macOS Catalina
- Python 3.7.5
- Tkinter 8.6

Comment: Read up on [SPECIFYING FILE PATTERNS](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/getOpenFile.htm#M16) about ***wild card characters (* and ?)***

Comment: I have this exact same problem on macOS Catalina 10.15.5, python 3.7.6 downloaded from python.org, Tk/Tcl version 8.6.8 (built-in). Same code runs correctly on linux Ubuntu 20.24. I believe your code is correct. If you find a solution, please tell me about it.

Comment: I believe this is a macOS bug.

Comment: My computer also sometimes say `2020-07-20 10:27:23.723 Python[85149:23405473] *** Assertion failure in void simulateAppSendEvent(NSEvent *, void (^)(NSEvent *))(), /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/ViewBridge/ViewBridge-464.1/ViewBridgeUtilities.m:487` when the buttons are grayed out.

Comment: @Santi-Santichaivekin Does the issue still persist with Python 3.8.5?

Comment: @Space Do you think this issue relates to Python version? I checked with 3.8.0(installed with Pyenv) and it did not work.

Comment: @stovfl Tried different wild card patterns, like `*.* or  *, *.py or .py...` and no effect as of this case. I believe this issue is not related to how to specify file patterns.

Comment: @SantiSantichaivekin it is also OK running in Windows Subsystem Unbuntu 18.04.

Comment: @Kuo It also works on Windows' installation of python without linux subsystem.

Comment: @Space haven't tried, I need to use pyinstaller and the pyinstaller website says pyinstaller only worked with python <=3.7

Comment: FWIW this code runs without error and allows me to pick and filter files as expected on MacOS 13.4.1, Python 3.10.5

Answer (score 0):

Well, when I run your code in my Python Shell, it works perfectly. I really can't do anything about your `Filter` error, but I have modified your file so that you can access those filetypes easily. I have inserted an `input()` code so that you can choose which filetype you want to access.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

# from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
# from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilenames

filetypes = input("Enter Filetype: ")
while True:
    if "All Files" in filetypes:
        ft = [("All Files", "*.*")]
        break
    elif "Python" in filetypes:
        ft = [("Python Files", "*.py")]
        break
    elif "Image" in filetypes:
        ft = [("Image Files", "*.bmp")]
        break
    else:
        continue


def OpenFile():

    p = askopenfilename(initialdir="../",
                        filetypes=ft,
                        title="Choose a file.")
    print("Path to File: \n", p)
    # Using try in case user types in unknown file
    # or closes without choosing a file.
    # try:
    #     with open(p, 'r') as f:
    #         print("Content of File:\n", f.read())
    # except:
    #     print("Error!")


root = Tk()
root.title("File Opener")
label = ttk.Label(root,
                  text="File Read Test!",
                  foreground="red",
                  font=("Helvetica", 16))
label.pack()

menu = Menu(root)
root.geometry("300x200")
root.config(menu=menu)

file = Menu(menu)
file.add_command(label='Open', command=OpenFile)
file.add_command(label='Exit', command=root.quit)
menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -2):

On my system:

- macOS Mojave 10.4.6
- Python 3.8.0
- TkVersion 8.6

I found this simple workaround got me the desired behavior:

```
filetypes = [ 
            ("All Files", "*.*"),
            ("Python File", "*.py"), 
            ("Image File", "*.bmp"),
            ]
```

That is, by having it come up with `"All Files"` initially, then switching to the other types in the open dialog filtered the files appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I rerun this code with **Python 3.8.0** and different filetypes combinations, the filters problem are the same. I use **Pyenv** to create virtual environment and **macOS Catalina 10.15.1**. And I also checked **Python 3.6.9, 3.7.3** by **Conda** virtual env. ALL can not choose filetypes through _Options-->Filters_